# Strange crash involving boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a custom library that I am tesing. I have both unit tests and component tests. The unit tests exercise all of the same code as the component test. The main difference is that the component test has to start a separate thread to run my library code. When it does this, I start to see the crash highlighted below. Some points to note:

1. I am linking agaisnt libboost_system, libboost_thread, pthread, rt, etc.
2. The same call stack is exercised in the unit tests without issue.
3. I checked to make sure that there isn't an *-mt version of boost thread. I am certain that the one I am linking against has threading support.
4. The crash does not occur on a linux host. Only freebsd.
5. I check for stack overflow. the context below uses about 42KB of stack space between the first and last frame. I am setting the stack size explicitly to 1MB for the boost thread I spawn.

I am fresh out of ideas. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  strcat () at /usr/src/lib/libc/i386/string/strcat.S:50
50      pushl   %edi            /* save edi */
(gdb) bt
#0  strcat () at /usr/src/lib/libc/i386/string/strcat.S:50
#1  0x2831f603 in tzload (name=0x2834baa0 "UTC", sp=0x283644a0, doextend=1) at /usr/src/lib/libc/stdtime/localtime.c:427
#2  0x2831fe6f in gmtload (sp=0x0) at /usr/src/lib/libc/stdtime/localtime.c:1203
#3  0x2831fea6 in gmt_init () at /usr/src/lib/libc/stdtime/localtime.c:1477
#4  0x28138f60 in _pthread_once (once_control=0x28361560, init_routine=0x2831fe89 <gmt_init at /usr/src/lib/libc/stdtime/localtime.c:1471>)
    at /usr/src/lib/libthr/thread/thr_once.c:87
#5  0x28323590 in _once (once_control=0x28361560, init_routine=0x2831fe89 <gmt_init at /usr/src/lib/libc/stdtime/localtime.c:1471>)
    at /usr/src/lib/libc/gen/_once_stub.c:62
#6  0x2831ecb1 in gmtsub (timep=0xbf7fcca4, offset=0, tmp=0xbf7fcc6c) at /usr/src/lib/libc/stdtime/localtime.c:1492
#7  0x2831ed3c in gmtime_r (timep=0xbf7fcca4, tmp=0xbf7fcc6c) at /usr/src/lib/libc/stdtime/localtime.c:1564
#8  0x080ab51b in boost::date_time::c_time::gmtime (t=0xbf7fcca4, result=0xbf7fcc6c) at ../../../contrib/opensource/boost/boost/date_time/c_time.hpp:85
#9  0x080ac4da in boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>::now() ()
#10 0x080a7f99 in expires_from_now (this=0x81181b0) at ../../../contrib/opensource/boost/boost/asio/detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp:155
#11 expires_from_now (this=0x81181b0) at ../../../contrib/opensource/boost/boost/asio/deadline_timer_service.hpp:124
#12 expires_from_now (this=0x81181b0) at ../../../contrib/opensource/boost/boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp:410
#13 smf::service::Manager::arm_degraded_services_timer (this=0x81181b0) at Manager.cpp:247
#14 0x080a8747 in smf::service::Manager::defer_degraded_service (this=0x81181b0, service=0x825c140) at Manager.cpp:269
#15 0x080a8948 in smf::service::Manager::service_signal_handler (this=0x81181b0, error_code=..., signal_number=20) at Manager.cpp:203
#16 0x080aa267 in operator() (owner=0x8123060, base=0x82567c0) at ../../../contrib/opensource/boost/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:280
#17 operator()<boost::_mfi::mf2<void, smf::service::Manager, const boost::system::error_code&, int>, boost::_bi::list2<const boost::system::error_code&, const int&> > (owner=0x8123060, base=0x82567c0) at ../../../contrib/opensource/boost/boost/bind/bind.hpp:392
#18 operator()<boost::system::error_code, int> (owner=0x8123060, base=0x82567c0) at ../../../contrib/opensource/boost/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:102
#19 operator() (owner=0x8123060, base=0x82567c0) at ../../../contrib/opensource/boost/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:118
#20 asio_handler_invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, smf::service::Manager, boost::system::error_code const&, int>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<smf::service::Manager*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::system::error_code, int> > (owner=0x8123060, base=0x82567c0)
    at ../../../contrib/opensource/boost/boost/asio/handler_invoke_hook.hpp:64
#21 invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, smf::service::Manager, boost::system::error_code const&, int>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<smf::service::Manager*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::system::error_code, int>, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, smf::service::Manager, boost::system::error_code const&, int>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<smf::service::Manager*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > > > (
    owner=0x8123060, base=0x82567c0) at ../../../contrib/opensource/boost/boost/asio/detail/handler_invoke_helpers.hpp:39
#22 boost::asio::detail::signal_handler<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, smf::service::Manager, boost::system::error_code const&, int>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<smf::service::Manager*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > > >::do_complete (owner=0x8123060, base=0x82567c0)
    at ../../../contrib/opensource/boost/boost/asio/detail/signal_handler.hpp:68
#23 0x080a6243 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) ()
#24 0x080a2b61 in run (this=0x811818c) at ../../../contrib/opensource/boost/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:59
#25 smf::service::Daemon::run (this=0x811818c) at Daemon.cpp:48
#26 0x080b69a8 in boost::(anonymous namespace)::thread_proxy (param=0x8124080) at ../src/pthread/thread.cpp:143
#27 0x281346a5 in thread_start (curthread=0x8136d80) at /usr/src/lib/libthr/thread/thr_create.c:288
#28 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: It says segmentation fault, we need to see the last 5 lines that are causing the crash

Comment: I'm gonna go out in a limb and say you are passing a datetime that is empty or incorrectly formatted or that is destroyed along that process and everything dies in the thread. It is not fault of boot.thread by the looks of it.

Answer (score 0):

From reading that backtrace I detect a fair bit of additional complexity you're not quite mentioning.

It appears you're using Boost Asio.

At some point you handle a [signal 20 (SIGCHLD)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal+7) (which would usually be ignored). The handler is `smf::service::Manager::service_signal_handler` which proceeds to call     `smf::service::Manager::defer_degraded_service`.

This then tries to "arm" a time using `expires_from_now` on a `deadline_timer`.

This is basically where things go sour. I'd check

- that the timer is actually still a valid reference (it didn't get moved/destroyed)
- that UTC is actually a valid timezone on the target platform
- that the timer is being protected from concurrent access (the `deadline_timer` class is **not** thread safe).

  A common way to do this is to have the `deadline_timer` on a *`strand`* (or just an `io_service` with one thread) and post a job on this strand/service to set the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was due to the fact that I was calling popen elsewhere in the program, which installs its own SIGCHLD handler. Badness ensued.